How to make a grid of plots that include subplots?
Ηi, I want to create a grid of plots that each plot has a subplot. The reason for this is that one of my columns (area1) has very high values compared to the other (area2, area3), therefore making the rest look negligible.
Here is my current code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'Year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015],
    'area1': [800000, 810000, 820000, 830000, 840000, 850000],
    'area2': [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500],
    'area3': [500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]}
population = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {
    'Year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015],
    'area1': [15000, 16000, 17000, 18000, 19000, 20000],
    'area2': [400, 450, 460, 460, 470, 480],
    'area3': [200, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290]}
houses = pd.DataFrame(data2)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(18, 8))
# Population
sns.lineplot(data=population, x='Year', y='area1', ax=axes[0], marker='o', linewidth=2.5, color='#9c2643', label='area1')
sns.lineplot(data=population, x='Year', y='area2',ax=axes[0], marker='o', linewidth=2.5, color='#1d2a6b', label='area2')
sns.lineplot(data=population, x='Year', y='area3', ax=axes[0], marker='o', linewidth=2.5, color='#e77148', label='area3')
axes[0].set_xlabel('Year')
axes[0].set_xlabel('Year')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Population')
axes[0].set_title('Population / Year')
axes[0].legend_.remove()

# Houses
sns.lineplot(data=houses, x='Year', y='area1', ax=axes[1], marker='o', linewidth=2.5, color='#9c2643', label='area1')
sns.lineplot(data=houses, x='Year', y='area2', ax=axes[1], marker='o', linewidth=2.5, color='#1d2a6b', label='area2')
sns.lineplot(data=houses, x='Year', y='area3', ax=axes[1], marker='o', linewidth=2.5, color='#e77148', label='area3')
axes[1].set_xlabel('Year')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Number of houses')
axes[1].set_title('Number of houses / Year')
axes[1].legend_.remove()

plt.show()


I have managed to achieve what I need when I want to plot one attribute at a time. Here is my code:
sns.set(font='sans-serif', font_scale=1.4)
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.despine()
# Create figure and adjust spines
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
# Define height ratios for subplots
height_ratios = [0.5, 2]  # Main plot takes twice the space of the second plot
# Create subplots with specified height ratios
gs = plt.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=height_ratios)
# Create subplot for high values
ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])  # Second subplot (High Values Plot)
sns.lineplot(data=population, x='Year', y='area1', marker='o', linewidth=2.5, color='black', linestyle='dashed', label='area1')
plt.ylabel('Population')
#Common title
plt.title('Population', fontweight="bold")
# Remove the legend from the first subplot
ax0.legend().remove()
# Hide x-axis labels and ticks
ax0.set_xticks([])  # Remove x-axis ticks
ax0.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=False)  # Hide x-axis labels
# Remove x-axis label
ax0.set_xlabel('')
# Main plot
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1])  # First subplot (Main plot)
sns.lineplot(data=population, x='Year', y='area2', marker='o', linewidth=2.5, color='#9c2643', label='area2')
sns.lineplot(data=population, x='Year', y='area3', marker='o', linewidth=2.5, color='#1d2a6b', label='area3')
#plt.title('Main Plot')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Population')
# Common y-axis label
plt.ylabel('Population', labelpad=20)
plt.xlabel('Year', labelpad=20)
# Create a common legend outside the subplots
handles0, labels0 = ax0.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles1, labels1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = handles0 + handles1
labels = labels0 + labels1
plt.tight_layout()  # Adjust layout to prevent overlapping
plt.show()


However, I cannot apply something similar when I want to create the grid of the plots. I need to plot multiple attributes so I want a solution that can support the grid of plots. Any suggestions?

The easier option is to use log scale on the y-axis, which also makes comparing all the areas easier. axes[0].set_yscale('log') and axes[1].set_yscale('log')

See Plot Figure, as per this answer of the duplicate.
